# Restrict cut/copy and paste between applications in android

Tags: android, copy-paste, clipboarddata

I want to restrict the procedure cut/copy inside the application and paste outside the application. However i must be able to cut/copy and paste with in my application. How do i implement this?

The problem i am facing is once i come out of the application i try to paste it doesn't paste anything but if i open clip board then i can see all the items i have stored in my clip board from my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i implement this?

You don't use the clipboard. The clipboard is a device-wide system service. Anything you put there will be available to other applications.

You are welcome to create your own "clipboard" construct inside your app and attempt to use it. This will not be completely reliable, insofar as you will be unable to control the behavior of `EditText` and the system clipboard on all devices, but that may or may not be your particular area of concern.

Comment: How do i create my own clipboard? If i create my own clipboard will that be persistent only to my application and would the contents of it get reflected in the global clipboard as well or the contents of custom clipboard are not shown in global clipboard?

Comment: @sundeep: "How do i create my own clipboard?" -- by programming. Create a class called `SundeepClipboard` and teach it how to hold onto stuff that you "copy" and "paste".

Comment: SundeepClipboard means something like creating my own clipboard functionality from scratch without using clipboard manager right.
 
can i find a solution to my problem by implementing Clipboardmanager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener  or is it just used to change the way your clipboard manager copies and pastes more complex data.

Answer (score 2):

Well i think this should work.

use
[ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html) class

if it

```
hasText()
```

see if  using clipdata.newPlainText method to add empty string to the clipboard in your onPause() method can solve it.

Comment: hasText and setText has been deprecated,he should use hasPrimaryClip() and setPrimaryClip(ClipData clip) instead

Comment: that's true but hasPrimaryClip() and setprimaryClip(clipData clip) are available only after API level 11.

Comment: Hi technoguff i was following the same procedure as you have told but when i paste it contains first content as blank but second content on clipboard is the text copied.

Comment: sorry i was wrong about setText() method. i have edited the answer.

Comment: The problem i am facing is once i come out of the application i try to paste it doesn't paste anything but if i open clip board then i can see all the items i have stored in my clip board from my application.

Comment: sorry that wouldn't work and this is something related to clip board history. As i have mentioned it doesn't paste but when we open the clip board it has an empty messege and the content copied from the application.